# turning off iPhone accelerometer while not using it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, accelerometer

At a spot in my game there is a **brief** use of the accelerometer.  I use this code:

```
UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.delegate = self;
accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
```

to start the accelerometer and then update it using:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accellerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

    if (whichLevel == 24) {
        //Blah blah blah, using accelerometer 
    } else {
        //Turn accelerometer off somehow?
    }
//I have found out using this:
NSLog(@"Accelerometer being used");
//That the accelerometer is being used after I start it in the game.
}
```

And of course, in the .h I put a   
This sort of code is used in more than a few tutorials-- But my point is, this is only used for a brief period, and I would like a way to turn it off while I am not using it.  (Which none of the tutorials show you how to do)

Apple seems to say here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html
 -- that you should use

```
[motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
```

but apparently you have to set it up that way in order to stop it that way.  Do I have to change how I set it up in order to end it??  Or can I end it using what I have?

Thanks in advance,

The Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the accelerometer’s delegate to `nil` should let it know that you don’t need its updates anymore. It still might not get powered off entirely—the system watches it to deliver orientation-change events, for instance—but your app won’t be responsible for that.